# How can I use a php variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

If I have created a variable in php, say `$test`, how can I set a variable in javascript, say `var test`, to be equal to it.

I have already tried `var test = <?php $test ?>`

Answer (score 2):

I guess

```
var test = <?php echo json_encode($test) ?>
```

The naive way `var test = '<?php echo ($test) ?>'` will fail if `$test` contains quotes or newlines, let alone is not of the string type (e.g. array, object)

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = '<?php echo $test; ?>'
```

Comment: Try it with `$test="bug's"`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
var test = '<?php echo  $test ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`var test = <?php $test ?>`

to

`var test = <?php echo $test; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = '<?php echo $test; ?>';
```

Or using shorthand echos, like this:

```
var test = '<?= test;?>';
```

Comment: Try it with `$test="bug's"`.

Comment: "Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available." Unless told otherwise, I believe it's safe to assume, atleast PHP 5.4.0 is used.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two things:

```
var test = <?php $test ?>
```

1) Echo statement.

2) Single Quotes around PHP snipplet.

So, the corrected code should be:

```
var test = "<?php echo $test ?>";
```

Comment: Try it with `$test="bug's"`.

Comment: @thg435, please suggest the answer then:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<pre>
var test = '<?php echo $test?>';
</pre>
```

below the definition of $test.

Answer (score 0):

Within your page where you want your PHP to output to type:

```
var MyJavascriptVariable = <?php echo $myPHPVariable; ?>
```

Advise NOT to use short tags () as this can be disabled by webhosts and may break your code.